# Implementing a little more complex conditions for a flow in Camunda

Tags: java, bpmn, camunda, juel

How can I implement more complex expression in a flow's condition? Simple conditions like:

```
${i > 0}
```

are handy and great but there are other times I need to do something a little more complex like:

```
${deadLine.after(now)}
```

Assuming `deadLine` is an object of type `Date` already defined in process instance and `now` means `new Date()`. How can I implement such expressions in a flow's condition? In Java I can:

```
ExpressionFactory factory = new ExpressionFactoryImpl();
SimpleContext context = new SimpleContext(new SimpleResolver());
factory.createValueExpression(context, "${deadLine}", java.util.Date.class).setValue(context, new java.util.Date());
factory.createValueExpression(context, "${now}", java.util.Date.class).setValue(context, new java.util.Date());
ValueExpression expr1 = factory.createValueExpression(context, "${deadLine.after(now)}", boolean.class);
System.out.println("Result = " + expr1.getValue(context));
```

But how can I do the same in a flow's condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you have a process variable named `deadLine` that is a `java.util.Date` object, you can write:

`${deadLine.after(now())}`

This works because Camunda provides a function `now` in the expression context [[1]](http://docs.camunda.org/7.3/guides/user-guide/#process-engine-expression-language-internal-context-functions).

There are several other ways to evaluate complex decision logic, for example:

- invoke a Spring or CDI bean that codes the decision in Java
- Use a script/service task or execution listener before the condition is evaluated that executes the decision logic and stores the result in a boolean process variable

I recommend reading this: http://docs.camunda.org/7.3/guides/user-guide/#process-engine-expression-language-variables-and-functions-available-inside-expression-language